Does Visual Studio 2022 support dev containers for .net projects?
I would like to setup dev containers for my .net team so that they can use the same development environment, including resources. They use Visual Studio 2022. This has been possible in VS Code and in VS 2022 for C++ projects. Whenever I search for C# and .NET I am directed to Visual Studio Container Tools which seems to be a different product. Can Visual Studio Container Tools be used to setup dev containers for .net projects or do I have to wait for .net dev container support? Is anybody aware of any announcements in that direction?

At least with VS Code you can create a language-agnostic development environment. The typical process is to create a devcontainer.json, define the settings (including VS Code extensions), create a Dockerfile with the environment for .net, or several Dockerfiles and a compose.yaml if you need more services. This way you get the same environment, the same extensions, and basically the same everything.

As of now this is not supported, you can upvote the suggestion for this: Support for Dev Containers in Visual Studio 2022 for .Net based projects
